# JavaScript: Stopping form from refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get my form to stop refreshing on submit and instead I would like to make an ajax call, I haven't done the ajax part yet but its still refreshing?

What have you tried?
I have took suggestions on the forum and added 'return false;' after the function is called onSubmit?

```
$('#message_form').submit(function() {
    postMessage();
    return false;
});

function postMessage() {
    var isValid = true;

    var username = document.forms["post_message_form"]["username"].value;
    var message = document.forms["post_message_form"]["message"].value;

    var errorMessage = "Something went wrong, try again!";

    if (isEmpty(username) || isEmpty(message)) {
        errorMessage = "You can't post with an empty name or message.";
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (!isValid) {
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
    else {
        alert("Your message has been posted.");
    }

    return false;
}

function isEmpty(field) {
    return field == null || field == "";
}
```

Form:

```
<form id="message_form" name="post_message_form" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Whats your name?" name="username">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Whats your message?" name="message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="message_form" value="Submit Message">
        </form>
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) might not be the best possible name for a global function.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Updated

There can be certain reasons regarding this kind of issue

- `postMessage` is not accessible

  There may be chances that this message is not globally declared
- There may be other error in javascript code

  Some some piece of code does not work due to error in other parts of javascript code
- There may be chances that you have not loaded jquery core library file

  If have not include `jquery.min.js` file your above code will not work (your case - *See comments*)

Since return false and event.preventDefault(); do the same work in this example you can use one of them

```
$('#message_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    postMessage();
    // return false;
});
```

To debug the code and find the error you can open developer tools in browser by pressing **f12** or select option **inspect element** by clicking right click on the page

Comment: It still refreshed, even after adding this.

Comment: Then there must be a error, have you checked your console?

Comment: Hi, I have an error saying $ is not defined (on page load)?

Comment: And this error is before or after you call preventDefault? Did you import ajax lib?

Comment: you haven't include jquery core file Inlcude https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js before the above code

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the issue.

Comment: why are you `preventDefault();` and `return false` one or the other would be adequate

Answer (score 0):

Try this code added `onsubmit="return postMessage()`

```
<form id="message_form" name="post_message_form" method="post" onsubmit="return postMessage()">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Whats your name?" name="username">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Whats your message?" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="message_form" value="Submit Message">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="message_form" name="post_message_form" method="post" onsubmit="return postMessage();">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Whats your name?" name="username">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Whats your message?" name="message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="message_form" value="Submit Message">
        </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

use preventDefault instead return false;

```
$('#message_form').submit(function(event) {
    console.log(123);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

https://codepen.io/animhotep/pen/bRBmxm?editors=1011

like in official maual ;) https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: how this answer is different from mine? Anyways try to read comment first and u will see his issue was resolved, he hasn't include the jquery core file See comments.

Comment: you have used useless return false; and haven't example